# Replace every span element

Tags: php, xslt

I'm trying to match multiple span elements within a DOM Document.

Here is the XSLT I'm currently using :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="html">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/html/body">
      <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/html/head">
      <head>
          <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
          <link type="text/css" href="additional-style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      </head>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//script|//style|//link|//meta">
      <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/html/body/*">
      <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//span">
      HELLO I'M A SPAN
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently, no matter where I put the `<xsl:template match="//span">` in the XSLT document, the spans never changes. If I remove `<xsl:template match="/html/body/*">` section, it does works. How can I keep the previous behavior and making the `span` matching active ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
  <xsl:template match="/html/body/*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

to make sure child nodes are processed with matching template. However usually this is achieved simply with

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Also note that in match patterns a leading `//` is not necessary so doing e.g. `<xsl:template match="script">...</xsl:template>` is just fine.

Comment: Works great, thanks. Care to give a links that explains what is that `@* | node()` ? Edit: Voted up, will validated asap.

Comment: That template with `match="@* | node()"` I posted is the so called identity transformation template, it matches attribute nodes (`@*`) and all other kind of nodes except namespace nodes and the root node and does a shallow copy of the node itself and then processes any attribute nodes and any child nodes. It is usually a starting point of a stylesheet that wants to copy some nodes of the input and then manipulate/transform or delete others as you can easily add further templates with more specific match patterns.